# Matrix with equal sum of rows and columns

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have NxM matrix with integer elements, greater or equal than 0.

From any cell I can transfer 1 to another one (-1 to the source cell, +1 to the destination).
Using this operation, I have to make sums for all rows and columns equal. The question is how to find the minimal amount of such operations to achieve my task. During the processing cells may be negative.

For example, for

1 1 2 2

1 0 1 1

0 0 1 1

1 1 1 2

The answer is 3.

P.s.: I've tried to solve it on my own, but came only to brute-force solution.

Comment: @Mixo123: this kind of question gets good answers if the questioner shows some evidence of having tackled the problem on his/her own.  Right now it looks as if you just want us to do your work for you.  Some SOers will, many won't.

Comment: I have tried, but no ideas. Only brute-force solution

Comment: Are you sure that the problem always has solution (looks like sum of all elements un the matrix should divide over M and N)? What about Nx1 matrix? Or you're getting matrix which can be sorted in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the one dimensional case: you have an array of numbers and you are allowed a single operation: take 1 from the value of one of the elements of the array and add it to other element. The goal is to make all elements equal with minimal operations. Here the solution is simple: you choose random "too big number" and add one to random "too small" number. Let me now describe how this relates to the problem at hand.

You can easily calculate the sum that is needed for every column and every row. This is the total sum of all elements in the matrix divided by the number of columns or rows respectively. From then on you can calculate which rows and columns need to be reduced and which - increased. see here:

```
1 1 2 2 -2
1 0 1 1 +1
0 0 1 1 +2
1 1 1 2 -1
+1+2-1-2
Expected sum of a row: 4
Expected sum of a column: 4
```

So now we generate two arrays: the array of displacements in the rows: `-2,+1,+2,-1` and the number of displacements in the columns: `+1,+2,-1,-2`. For this two arrays we solve the simpler task described above. It is obvious that we can not solve the initial problem in fewer steps than the ones required for the simpler task (otherwise the balance in the columns or rows will not be 0).

However I will prove that the initial task can be solved in exactly as many steps as is the maximum of steps needed to solve the task for the columns and rows:

Every step in the simpler task generates two indices `i` and `j`: the index from which to subtract and the index to which to add. Lets assume in a step in the column task we have indices `ci` and `cj` and in the row task we have indices `ri` and `rj`. Then we assign a correspondence of this in the initial task: take 1 from `(ci, ri)` and add one to `(cj, rj)`. At certain point we will reach a situation in which there might be still more steps in, say, the columns task and no more in the rows task. So we get `ci` and `cj`, but what do we do for `ri` and `rj`? We just choose `ri`=`rj` so that we do not screw up the row calculations.

In this solution I am making use of the fact I am allow to obtain negative numbers in the matrix.

Now lets demonstrate:

```
Solution for columns:
4->1;3->2;4->2
Solution for rows:
1->3;1->3;2->4

Total solution:
(4,1)->(1,3);(3,1)->(2,3);(4,2)->(2,4)
```

Comment: And what if all rows are '+' and all columns are neutral or '-'?

Comment: @boris Maybe it will be better distinguish between row state and column state for each cell.

Comment: @boris,Will it be polite to suggest a (possible) improvement as an answer?

Comment: Ok, fine. Now I have new, improved solution

Comment: @Eugeny89, of course it will be. Actually you should have already, because now I posted my own improved version

Answer (score 3):

First, find the expected sum per row and per column <sup>1</sup>.

```
rowSum = totalSum / numRows
colSum = totalSum / numCols
```

Then, iterate through the rows and the columns and compute the following values:

```
rowDelta = 0
for each row r
    if sum(r) > rowSum
       rowDelta += sum(r) - rowSum

colDelta = 0
for each col c
    if sum(c) > colSum
       colDelta += sum(c) - colSum
```

The number of the minimum moves to equilibrate all the rows and columns is:

```
minMoves = max(rowDelta, colDelta)
```

This works because you have to transfer from rows that exceed `rowSum` into rows that don't exceed it, and from columns that exceed `colSum` into columns that don't exceed it.

If initially `rowDelta` was lower than `colDelta`, then you will attain a stage where you equilibrated all the rows, but the columns are still not equilibrated. At this case, you will continue transferring from cells to other cells in the same row. The same applies if initially `colDelta` was lower than `rowDelta`, and that's why we selected the maximum between them as the expected result.

<sub><sup>1</sup> If `totalSum` is not a multiple of `numRows` or `numCols`, then the problem has no solution.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Supose thar `r1` is the index of a row with maximal sum, while `r2` is the row with minimal sum. `c1` column with maximal sum and `c2` column with minimal.

You need to repeat the following operation:

1. if `Matrix[r1][c1] == Matrix[r2][c2]` we're done!
2. Otherwise, `Matrix[r1][c1] -= 1` and `Matrix[r2][c2] += 1`