# Sum of Matrix Rows and Columns for Real Number Entries

Tags: math, matrix

Please, forgive my lack of details, but my question is exactly the same as the hyperlink. Nevertheless, for cases where all entries belong to R. 
Entries a_{i,j} in the matrix are Reals, but what one can add and subtract remains {+1, -1}

Thanks.
[Similar problem, but for integers. I want an algorithm for Real entries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859737/matrix-with-equal-sum-of-rows-and-columns)

Comment: Have you tried the 3rd answer given in that link? I don't think it's integer dependent (on first glance anyway).

Comment: Are you suggesting that you are allowed to add/subtract arbitrary real number amounts instead of 1, as long as the total sum is preserved?

Comment: Please, check the new edits, DanielV. mbratch, I have not tried, but will do soon.

Comment: The only difference is that the task of making rows/columns equal may not be possible if there is a fractional amount in the wrong place. Just ignore the decimal part of the row/column totals and you'll end up with the closest solution.

Comment: Thank you, clwhisk that did the job.